# View moves on fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the following code to redraw a fragment:

```java
getActivity()
  .getSupportFragmentManager()
  .beginTransaction()
  .replace(R.id.container, this.getClass(), null)
  .commit();
```

Relevant code in the activity:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

And finally relevant code in the fragment:

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background"
        tools:context=".ui.list.ListFragment">

(...)

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/add_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/foreground"
            app:tint="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add_boadskip"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

On creation the `FloatingActionButton` is above the `BottomNavigationView`. But when I redraw the fragment, the `FloatingActionButton` sticks to the end of screen, being overlapped by the `BottomNavigationView`. How can I prevent this from happening when I redraw the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You should use power of coordinator layout. Remove gravity attributes from fab button and add
`app:layout_anchor=id of bottomview`
`:app:layout_anchorGravity=bottom|end`

More about Coordinator layout is [here](https://medium.com/android-news/coordinatorlayout-basic-8040c74cf426)

Comment: Using the id of the bottomview gives an Exception:
```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find CoordinatorLayout descendant view with id be.allersma.boadskipje:id/nav_view to anchor view com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
```

I presume this is because `@id/nav_view` is not in the fragment, but in the activity.